# Using formarray in Reactive forms angular 5 to dynamically add forms

Tags: typescript, angular5

I need to do some computation in other forms I dynamically generated using `formarray` but it only works on the first one. Please how do I make it work for other forms?

This is my code

```
let control = this.proposalForm.controls.proposals['controls'][0];

this.proposalForm.get('TotalProposedAmount').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
        this.originalBalance = val;
        console.log(val)
    })

    control.controls['ProposedAmount'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {

            this.details.CurrentBalance = this.originalBalance - value;
            this.latestOutstandingBalance = this.details.CurrentBalance;

                })
```